# misunderstood Error installation of the right packages/ moduling to create a map of counties of IOWA, USA

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly, maps, geopandas

I saw on: https://plotly.com/python/county-choropleth/
the following Example code and adjusted to my Jupiter Notebook and it worked, but now something went wrong and the error I recieve indicate missing packages/ modules, and I am kinda new to python and tried many things that didn't work
please help me what packages/ modules do I miss?

> !pip install plotly-geo==1.0.0
> !pip install geopandas==0.3.0
> !pip install pyshp==1.2.10
> !pip install shapely==1.6.3
>
> import plotly.figure_factory as ff
>
> import numpy as np
> import pandas as pd
>
> df_sample = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/minoritymajority.csv')
> df_sample_r = df_sample[df_sample['STNAME'] == 'Florida']
>
> values = df_sample_r['TOT_POP'].tolist()
> fips = df_sample_r['FIPS'].tolist()
>
> endpts = list(np.mgrid[min(values):max(values):4j])
> colorscale = ["#030512","#1d1d3b","#323268","#3d4b94","#3e6ab0",
> "#4989bc","#60a7c7","#85c5d3","#b7e0e4","#eafcfd"]
> fig = ff.create_choropleth(
> fips=fips, values=values, scope=['Florida'], show_state_data=True,
> colorscale=colorscale, binning_endpoints=endpts, round_legend_values=True,
> plot_bgcolor='rgb(229,229,229)',
> paper_bgcolor='rgb(229,229,229)',
> legend_title='Population by County',
> county_outline={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)', 'width': 0.5},
> exponent_format=True,
> )
> fig.layout.template = None
> fig.show()

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there has been a similar question in the [plotly community](https://community.plotly.com/t/usa-county-choropleth-maps-in-python/8578), but no solution. This is not recommended as it uses the previous map creation functionality; I suggest an alternative solution using a geojson file. Take the US geojson file from the reference and combine it with the Florida data. Use this combined geodata frame to visualize the population data. Change the target elements to the data that suits your purposes.

```
import pandas as pd

df_sample = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/minoritymajority.csv')
df_sample_r = df_sample[df_sample['STNAME'] == 'Florida']
values = df_sample_r['TOT_POP'].tolist()
fips = df_sample_r['FIPS'].tolist()

df_sample_r['FIPS'] = df_sample_r['FIPS'].astype('str') 

import geopandas as gpd

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json'
geo_counties = gpd.read_file(url)
geo_df = geo_counties.merge(df_sample_r, left_on='id', right_on='FIPS')
geo_df = geo_df.set_index('id')

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=geo_df.__geo_interface__,#json.loads(geo_df.to_json()), 
                                    locations=geo_df.index,
                                    z=geo_df['TOT_POP'],
                                    colorscale="Viridis",
                                    marker_opacity=0.5,
                                    marker_line_width=0.5
                                   ))

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                  mapbox_zoom=5,
                  mapbox_center = {"lat": 27.6648, "lon": -81.5157})
fig.update_layout(height=600, margin={"r":0,"t":20,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it did not work, but I solved it
what I was missing is:
 !pip install plotly-geo==1.0.0
 !pip install geopandas==0.9.0
 !pip install shapely==1.6.4
 !pip install pyshp==2.1